# WPMU widget use sitewide

Tags: multisite, widgets

I'm using a widget on a site with the `blogid 1`. But I want to use the same widget with the content from `blogid 1` in all of the other sites.

Is there a way to reuse this widget?

I tried the `switch_to_blog(1);` method so I have the right query, but this doesn't seem to be the method to include the widget with content.

---

Added after edit:

```
/*
Plugin Name: How it works (widget)
Description: "How it works" Widget
Version: 1
*/

class HHW_Widget extends WP_Widget {

    /**
     * Register widget with WordPress. (Sets up the widgets name etc)
     */
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(
            'hhw_widget', // Base ID
            __('Hoe het werkt blok', 'text_domain'), // Name
            array( 'description' => __( 'Blokken voor homepagina en hoe het werkt detail pagina.', 'text_domain' ), ) // Args
        );
    }

    /**
     * Front-end display of widget. (Outputs the content of the widget)
     *
     * @see WP_Widget::widget()
     *
     * @param array $args     Widget arguments.
     * @param array $instance Saved values from database.
     */
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );
        $block_1_excerpt = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['block_1_excerpt'] );
        $block_1_content = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['block_1_content'] );
        $svg_image = $instance['svg_image'];

        echo $args['before_widget'];

        echo '<div class="car-icn-container centered">';
        if ( ! empty( $svg_image ) ):
            echo $svg_image;
        endif;
        echo '</div>';

        if ( ! empty( $title ) ):
            echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];
        endif;

        if ( ! empty( $block_1_excerpt ) ):
            echo '<p>'.$block_1_excerpt.'</p>';
        endif;

        /*
        if ( ! empty( $block_1_content ) ):
            echo '<p>'.$block_1_content.'</p>';
        endif;
        */

        echo $args['after_widget'];
    }

    /**
     * Back-end widget form. (Ouputs the options form on admin)
     *
     * @see WP_Widget::form()
     *
     * @param array $instance Previously saved values from database.
     */
    public function form( $instance ) {
        if ( isset( $instance[ 'title' ] ) ) {
            $title = $instance[ 'title' ];
        }
        else {
            $title = __( 'Nieuw blok', 'text_domain' );
        }

        if ( isset( $instance[ 'block_1_excerpt' ] ) ) :
            $block_1_excerpt = $instance[ 'block_1_excerpt' ];
        endif;
        if ( isset( $instance[ 'block_1_content' ] ) ) :
            $block_1_content = $instance[ 'block_1_content' ];
        endif;

        if ( isset( $instance[ 'svg_image' ] ) ) :
            $svg_image = esc_textarea($instance[ 'svg_image' ]);
        endif;

        ?>

        <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Hoofd titel:' ); ?></label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>">
        </p>

        <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'block_1_excerpt' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Samenvatting:' ); ?></label> 
        <textarea class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'block_1_excerpt' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'block_1_excerpt' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $block_1_excerpt ); ?>"><?php echo esc_attr( $block_1_excerpt ); ?></textarea>
        </p>

        <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'block_1_content' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Content:' ); ?></label> 
        <textarea rows="6" class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'block_1_content' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'block_1_content' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $block_1_content ); ?>"><?php echo esc_attr( $block_1_content ); ?></textarea>
        </p>

        <hr />

        <div class="admin-fold-out">
            <a class="fold-trigger">
                SVG image embedden. (Geavanceerd)
            </a>
            <div class="fold-container">
                <p>
                    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'svg_image' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'SVG image:' ); ?></label> 
                    <textarea rows="6" class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'svg_image' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'svg_image' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_textarea( $svg_image ); ?>"><?php echo esc_textarea( $svg_image ); ?></textarea>
                </p>
            </div>
            <hr />
            <br />
        </div>

    <?php 
    }

    /**
     * Sanitize widget form values as they are saved. (Processing widget options on save)
     *
     * @see WP_Widget::update()
     *
     * @param array $new_instance Values just sent to be saved.
     * @param array $old_instance Previously saved values from database.
     *
     * @return array Updated safe values to be saved.
     */
    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = array();
        $instance['title'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['title'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] ) : '';
        $instance['block_1_excerpt'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['block_1_excerpt'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['block_1_excerpt'] ) : '';
        $instance['block_1_content'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['block_1_content'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['block_1_content'] ) : '';

        if ( current_user_can('unfiltered_html') )
            $instance['svg_image'] =  $new_instance['svg_image'];
        else
            $instance['svg_image'] = stripslashes( wp_filter_post_kses( addslashes($new_instance['svg_image']) ) ); // wp_filter_post_kses() expects slashed
            $instance['filter'] = isset($new_instance['filter']);

        return $instance;
    }

} // class HIW_Widget

// register HIW_Widget widget
function register_HHW_Widget() {
    register_widget( 'HHW_Widget' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'register_HHW_Widget' );
```

---

**Edit: code in theme, outside plugin**

```
switch_to_blog(1);

if ( is_active_sidebar('sidebar-customwidget') ) {
    echo '<div class="container this-blog-customWidgetSidebar">';
    dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-customwidget' );
    echo '</div>';

} else {
    // nothing
}

restore_current_blog();
```

This seems to be working. But only if I have the sidebar active on the child-website. So it'll get the right data out of it, but it seems that the `is_active_sidebar()` tag is still calling outside the 'swich_to_blog'.

Comment: There are a number of "RELATED" questions on the right that  may help but this question is light on detail. By "reuse" do you mean you want the widget automatically added or you just want it available on multiple blogs? Post the code for the widget, please.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Well... the widget itself isn't that interesting, it's just a title and a textarea. It's just that I want to use the content of the main website which has the blogid of 1 to be used on the other websites. I'll try the related posts tomorrow.

Comment: Sounds like the widget does need to be interesting enough to pull data from the main site?

Comment: Yes, this way there is always a default content from the main site. So I don't have to repeat it over and over.

Comment: There is no `switch_to_blog(1);` in your code or anything else that might retrieve data from the main blog?